# Sending reminders when an item expires

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, reminders

I want to build an application which sends reminders (SMS or Email) to users whose items, like in workflow, are about to expire or are overdue. The usual way is to poll the database after a timer triggers and calculate if anything is due and intimate users about it.

Is there any other better way than this polling mechanism?

EDIT:- Well for the scheduling I will go with [Quartz.net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net) scheduler.

Comment: I think I would stick to the old fashioned scheduler approach, events in your persistent storage and an application/scheduler firing the corresponding actions once they expire or are about to.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for pure ASP.NET solution, you can use Cache expiration mechanism. Insert an item into Cache with set expiration date/time and pass a callback function that will be called when the item expires.

Comment: Sorry if I'm wrong but are you sure you want to use a cache mechanism, which is -by nature- intended for transient data as the mechanism to trigger notifications for events -probably- way too far in the future?

Comment: quartznet.sourceforge.net will be far better and robust than `cache expiration`

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted down-to-the-second notification, you could do something extreme like use a BizTalk orchestration to create a long-running transaction which started a timer counting down to zero from now until the reminder was due. BizTalk can send email via SMTP.

But if your needs aren't that demanding, and to be honest using SMS/Email isn't guaranteed to arrive on time anyway, I would (and have in the past) taken the easier approach and use scheduled database polling as suggested by Raciel R.